# How can I use different punctuations in the same clauses?

Tags: punctuation

Are the punctuation and grammar correct in all these variations?

- A: The boss, Mike, is a bully; the way that he talks to you, and the way that he talks to his employees, it’s not right.
- B: Mick, the boss, is a bully; it’s the way he talks to you, and the way he talks to his employees: it is not right.
- C: Sadly, Mike is a bully. The way that he talks to his employees and you, it’s not right.
- D: Sadly, your boss is a bully; the way he talks to his employees, and you, it’s not right.

In the sentence “D”, is there a way to put the word “Mike” next to the word “your boss”?

Comment: You can say: is not right, instead of it's not right.

Comment: It depends on how closely the two sentences (main clauses) are related and what the relationship is. This is a matter of writerly judgment. If entirely separate, a period; if the second is an expansion of the first, consider a colon; if they're in contrast, a dash maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the examples are punctuated correctly.

A) contains a "comma splice".  You can't simply join two independent clauses with a comma.

> The boss, Mike, is a bully; the way that he talks to you, and the way
> that he talks to his employees >>,<< it’s not right.

You must write:

**The way that he talks to you, and the way that he talks to his employees *is* not right.**

or

**It's not right how the talks to you and his employees.**

If you are writing dialogue, you might use an *emdash*:

**The way that he talks to you and to his employees - it’s not right.**

(B) is also an inappropriate splice, this time misusing the semicolon.

> Mick, the boss, is a bully >>;<< it’s the way he talks to you, and the way
> he talks to his employees: it is not right.

Instead, write:

**Mick, the boss, is a bully.  The way he talks to you and his employees is not right.**

You must break up two independent clauses or use a connective.  If you used a connective such as 'and':

**The boss is a bully, and the way he talks to you and his employees is not right.**

(C) is close to natural and correctly punctuated, but again the "comma splice" is present.

> Sadly, Mike is a bully. The way that he talks to his employees and
> you >>,<< it’s not right.

Apply the same remedy here:

**The way that he talks to you and his employees is not right.**

In (D):

> Sadly, your boss is a bully; the way he talks to his employees, and
> you, it’s not right.

Comma splice again, but also another comma that should be deleted, after "employees".

You can read more about the "comma splice" and how to avoid it here:  https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma-splice/

Comment: Comma splices are hated by pedants who like inventing rules, but they're very common and a matter of stylistic preference. See [for instance this question on English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/537555/is-a-comma-splice-always-a-mistake) or several others. Personally, I'd use a colon to join the sentences.

Comment: Your opinions here do not change the fact that this would be marked wrong on standardized exams and make you less likely to be hired in a job requiring written communication skills. You do a great disservice to English learners to tell them to write comma splices. Yes, it is used in informal, colloquial speech, and as a matter of style. But, one must learn the basic rules before one can break them appropriately. (And in particular, the comma splices above would never be appropriate....)

Answer (score 0):

None of (A) thru (D) are grammatically wrong or unnatural.

On (B) "*it is not right.** seems slightly off.Perhaps simply changingm to  the contracted form:*it's not right*" would improve things.

On (D) "*Sadly, your boss is a bully;*" could become *Sadly, your boss, Mike,  is a bully;*"

On all but (C) one could replace the semi-colon with a period and create two valid sentences. That is a matter of style.

Comment: Thank you for answering!